# Save cmd commands in Intellij-idea

Tags: intellij-idea

Can Intellij Idea save cmd commands somewhere where I can see them, copy, sort them into folders and maybe see them in the terminal somehow for example?
I have txt file with a lot of commands in order not to forget them and do not write mostly used all the time.
just example:

```
cp /path1 /path2
rm -r /path
chown username /path
service name stop
service name start
service name restart
```

maybe Idea has some plugins for it but I did not find any of them.

Comment: You can use up/down arrows in the [IDE Terminal](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/terminal-emulator.html) to access previously used commands without typing. If you have command chains that need to be executed one by one consider using [External Tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-tools-external-tools.html) feature to execute them as scripts.

Comment: @EgorKlepikov u are right I know it. I mean that for example I have many environments and some of them may have other commands in history or somebody rewrited it or its a new env at all. And I wanna have some saved and sorted list of commands somewhere in Idea to at least copy them from there or to bind with some keys